# Javascript/Jquery Parse Json request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So my page make a request to a php page and that page return a JSON with an array result
PHP Return Example: `{"name":["Zizi","Zizi"],"position":["86","86"],"points":["26","26"]}`

Every name, position (json array ?) have multiple values how can I parse very value like
I'm using this code:

```
    $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
    $.getJSON('all.php', function(data) {
        $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+ data.name +"</p>");*/
    });
});
```

With this the jQuery type Zizi,Zizi, How can i ready or count the values inside the "name"

Answer (score 1):

`.length` is properties of array that gives you their count.

Use that like this: `data.name.length;`

Also, `getJSON` will only give you JSON string.

You've to parse it.

Do this:

```
$.getJSON('all.php', function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      var length=data.name.length;
      $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+ data.name +"</p>");*/
});
```

Comment: `data` is an object, using `data.name` accesses the value of the `name` key in the object and `name.length` returns the length of the value which is an array.

Comment: data.name.length return me undefined X:

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution I do not know if it's the most correct

```
    $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
    $.getJSON('all.php', function(data) {
      $(data.name).each(function(index){
                 $('#showdata').append('<p>Name = ' + data.name[index] +' Position= ' + data.position[index] + ' Points = ' + data.points[index] + '</p>');     
            });
    });
});
```